# How to set a background color defined as a CSS class (using JQuery eventually)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am still new to CSS/Javascript/JQuery. I am defining a couple of colors as classes in a css file. Then, I want to use one of them as the background color of a HTML page:

```
.wf_blue { color:rgb(2, 12, 40); }
.wf_white { color:rgb(255, 252, 247); }

body{background-color: wf_blue;}
```

The above does not work. I tried with JQuery, but unsuccessfully. I have seen other questions on SO, but could not figure out the solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the CSS should be:

```
.wf_blue { background-color: rgb(2, 12, 40); }
.wf_white { background-color: rgb(255, 252, 247); }
```

In plain HTML

```
<body class="wf_blue">
```

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").addClass("wf_blue");
});
```

Comment: This works when I define the color as a background color. I was wondering if it is possible to re-use a color as a background color. Is it?

Comment: No, `color` and `background-color` are separate. As topek says, look into SASS or LESS for reusable variables in CSS

Answer (score 3):

your classes can only be used in the HTML markup like this

```
<body class="wf_blue">....
```

Alternative you can set this class with jQuery

```
$('body').addClass('wf_blue');
```

If you would like to use variables in CSS, you can take a look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which are CSS preprocessors

Comment: When I do this, the background is not updated. It seems like I have to declare a background color in the CSS, not a color (then it works). I was wondering if it is possible to re-use a color as a background color.

Comment: No that's no how things work in CSS. Still, if you would like to reuse elements/colors take a look at the links above.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use variables in CSS, then you have to use an intermediate language, like [less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a javascript library (such as jquery or prototype), you can write directly:
A. HTML:

```
 <body class="wf_blue">
```

B. javascript:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName ('body') [0]. addClass ('wf_blue');
```

thanks